NextJS React production ready with fontawesome icons
How should I decreate the size of the bundles? We added fortawesome/fontawesome, but only some icons are used, about 20. Is it true that the bundle contains all the icons from the fontawesome icon sets?
Partial package.json content:
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "6.5.1",
"@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "6.5.1",
"@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "0.2.0",

I see in the output whenever I build the project:
[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of node_modules\@fortawesome\free-solid-svg-icons\index.mjs as it exceeds the max of 500KB.
[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of node_modules\lodash\lodash.js as it exceeds the max of 500KB.
[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of node_modules\@fortawesome\free-solid-svg-icons\index.mjs as it exceeds the max of 500KB.
[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of node_modules\lodash\lodash.js as it exceeds the max of 500KB.

Can I do something do decrease the size?

Yes, you can decrease the bundle size by only importing the specific icons you need instead of importing the entire @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons package:
// icons.js

import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
// import only icons you need
import { faCoffee, faCheckCircle, faTimesCircle } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

// Add icons to the library 
library.add(faCoffee, faCheckCircle, faTimesCircle);

Then you can use the imported icons like this:
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';

const Component = () => (
  <div>
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon="fa-coffee" />
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon="fa-check-circle" />
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon="fa-times-circle" />
  </div>
);


Seems very interesting, but what is the correlance between the two code. I use the 2nd one currently, but I cannot see the usage of the library defined in the first one.

Is it because on the 2nd you use "check-circle" instead of faCheckCircle?

@ZoltanHernyak the correlation between 2 snippets of code is that in the first snippet you only import icons you need, and in the second one you use it without importing icons directly, but just by referencing by icon name. Here is the explanation from the docs - https://docs.fontawesome.com/web/use-with/react/add-icons

@ZoltanHernyak I just updated the answer, added "fa-" prefixes to icons
